# What's the meaning of " got roasted by someone"?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "got roasted by"?

Answer (score 2):

A "roast" is a type of speech that honors a person while also making fun of him or her for comedic effect. In common parlance, it's become commonplace to use "got roasted" to mean a person received (possibly justified) verbal abuse, whether or not it's funny or meant to honor that person. So, saying someone "got roasted" can often mean the person was subject to verbal abuse and didn't have an adequate defense or comeback.

It could also mean the person had an event, like a birthday party, where speakers gave roast speeches about him or her. If you want to hear examples of this kind of comedy, you can find them on youtube.